# How do I get my server to recognise a change in users?

Tags: outlook

I'm new in post running a small charity.  As a result I've inherited a system from the previous manager that was poorly run.  In my enthusiasm to change login details etc. I appear to have killed my microsoft outlook account.  When trying to access outlook it prompts me for my user name, domain name and password - which I'm obviously not filling in correctly because it's not accepting my answers.  Is there a way to determine that information from the server side?  I have access to the server and the staff computers.

Comment: Help us out here with some descriptive tags. Windows Server 2003? Exchange server? Small business server?

Comment: The server is a small business server.  
thanks for the dressing down Joeqwerty!  Breaking something wasn't quite the first thing i did but I accept your point.

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't have an "Outlook" account. You have an AD user account, with an Exchange mailbox (presumably). Outlook uses your AD user account credentials (that you used to log on to your workstation) to connect to your Exchange mailbox.
2. You say that the previous admin did a poor job, but here you are and the first thing you do is break something. That's not saying much for you either is it?
3. What exactly was poorly run by the previous admin? Do you have specifics or are you just making a blanket statement because they didn't do the job the way you think it should have been done?
4. Trash talking the person who held your job before you doesn't serve you, them, or the organization.

My apologies for being harsh. I hate it when I hear someone lay blame with their predecessor. Whether they did a poor job or not, bad mouthing them serves no purpose except to make you look unprofessional. I've never in my career said negative things about the person who had the job before me. I simply evaluate the environment, take ownership of it, and do my job the way I believe it should be done. The guy before me was not perfect and I'm certainly not either.

Comment: +1 Agree 100% on the trash talking, though I think this is unintentional in this case, it could be very poorly received. Breaking something, on the other hand, is how we all learn our job. The key is to learn how to break things when they don't matter and fix them while no one notices.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you only killed Outlook and not your login credentials altogether?  Do you have Active Directory?  Can you access other hosts on your network by name?  If you want to see the domain tied to the account on your current machine, go to:

```
 Start > Control Panel > User Accounts
```